# Get RuntimeError: get_mkldnn_dtype: unsupported data type when try to initialize LSTM generator model

Tags: pytorch, conda, lstm, generative-adversarial-network, intel-mkl

I use pytorch to train GAN based on lstm on Windows machine. Cannot fix problem with mkl-dnn library.
**Code**:

```
class Generator(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, input_dim, output_dim, hidden_dim=256, num_layers=1):
        super().__init__()
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
        self.output_dim = output_dim

        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_dim, hidden_dim, num_layers, batch_first=True)
        self.linear = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(hidden_dim, output_dim), nn.Tanh())

    def forward(self, input):
        batch_size, seq_len = input.size(0), input.size(1)
        h_0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_dim, dtype=torch.float64)
        c_0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_dim,dtype=torch.float64)

        recurrent_features, _ = self.lstm(input, (h_0, c_0))
        outputs = self.linear(recurrent_features.contiguous().view(batch_size * seq_len, self.hidden_dim))
        outputs = outputs.view(batch_size, seq_len, self.output_dim)
        return outputs
```

**Call**:

```
    batch_size = 24
    len_seq = 10
    noise_dim = c.input_dim
    out_dim = c.input_dim

    gen = Generator(noise_dim,out_dim)
    noise = torch.randn(batch_size//2, len_seq, noise_dim)
    generator_out = gen(noise)
```

**Error**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "models\rcgan.py", line 82, in <module>
    generator_out = gen(noise)
              ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "project\src\models\rcgan.py", line 31, in forward
    recurrent_features, _ = self.lstm(input, (h_0, c_0))
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\rnn.py", line 812, in forward
    result = _VF.lstm(input, hx, self._flat_weights, self.bias, self.num_layers,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: get_mkldnn_dtype: unsupported data type
```

How could i fix it? Can I disable usage of mkl-dnn as backend? If not, how should I properly install it:  via `conda` or directly in machine.

Thank you for the help.

1)I tried google the problem
2)Installation of mkldnn via anaconda is stucked
3)I have successfully installed oneDNN but this doesn't solve the problem